# Composer package autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I can't get my library to work. The directory structure is lib-name/src and inside theres a main dir and a tests dir, how do I tell composer to load from the /lib-name/src/main folder?

Link to my library github https://github.com/gerardorn/catalogo

Comment: You must read about [psr-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 ways to [map your classes for autloading](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) with composer.

#### PSR-0

The recommended way is [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) compatible. This protocol describes the directory structure of your library. Each namespace need to be a directory. Classes with underscores are separated as well (PEAR style).

In your case, the class [Catalogable](https://github.com/gerardorn/catalogo/blob/master/src/main/Catalogable.php) has a namespace `gerardorn\catalogo`. To be PSR-0 compatible the directory structure is:

```
- src
   - main
      - gerardorn
         - catalogo
            - Catalogable.php
```

In your `composer.json` you should put the following:

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {"gerardorn" : "src/main"}
}
```

#### Classmap

Alternatively you could use `classmap`. Classes are searched for in the directory regardless of the namespace.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["src/main"]
}
```

#### Files

The 3th method `files` doesn't apply in your case.

---

## PHPUnit

Note that PHPUnit is needed to *test* your library, but not to *run* your library. Therefor you **shouldn't** put that up as a required library.

It's good that you're writing unit tests. You should sign up for [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/). It will run your PHPUnit tests each time that you push to GitHub and warn you (by e-mail) if something got broken.

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer, I had no idea about PSR-0, and I'm still learning to use composer.

Answer (score 2):

Your directory structure should be [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) compatible.

i.e. your file [Catalogable.php](https://github.com/gerardorn/catalogo/blob/master/src/main/Catalogable.php) has a namespace `gerardorn\catalogo`, so your directory structure for this has to match the following.

```
- src
    - main
        - gerardorn
            - catalogo
```